# MFMailComposeViewController only populating subject

Tags: iphone, ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

This code has been working for months now on my iPhone:

```
[mailComposer setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];

x = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

[x presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
[self.view addSubview:x.view];
```

I've set the subject, recipient email and body. It used to work fine. But now on my iPhone I get a very similar issue to the one described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824374/ui-toolbar-button-breaking-mail-composer-but-works-fine-with-regular-button

But I'm not using barbuttons, just a regular uibutton to trigger the mail composer.

My send button is greyed out. Only the subject is populated. When I try to edit any fields, the log window gives me "no keyboard". But when I hit cancel I get the same error:

```
_serviceViewControllerReady:error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceErrorDomain error 1.)"
```

Strangely the exact same code works fine on my iPad (same project, nothing different for iPad). Very strange. I don't think I even updated my iphone recently, so I don't know what could be causing this change in behavior. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Try to restart your device or iOS Simulator.